# Silverlight+ WCF Ria Service + FK object member is marked with XmlIgnore, can I prevent this from being added to the generated file?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, xml-serialization, wcf-ria-services, datacontractserializer

Using silverlight 4, with RIA Services Toolkit May 2010.

I have an Entity Data Model (.edmx) which contains a FK reference.

In my DomainContext Service class (which references my .edmx) I modified my GET method to include Include("FK_ENTITY_TABLE_NAME"):

```
public IQueryable<PARENT_ENTITY> GetPARENT_ENTITY()
{
    this.ObjectContext.PARENT_ENTITY.Include("FK_ENTITY_TABLE_NAME");
}
```

In my DomainContext Service Metadata class (.metadata.cs) named "internal sealed class PARENT_ENTITYMetadata" I added the [Include] attribute to the
 property which references my FK entity:

```
    [Include]
    public FK_ENTITY_TABLE_NAME { get; set; }
```

My generated (.g.cs) ria service proxy file contains the following DataContract with **XmlIgnore**:

```
private EntityRef<FK_ENTITY_TABLE_NAME_PARENT_ENTITY> _fk_entity_table_name;
public sealed partial class PARENT_ENTITY : Entity
{
...
        [Association("FK_ENTITY_TABLE_NAME_PARENT_ENTITY", "entity_id", ",entity_id", IsForeignKey=true)]
        [XmlIgnore()]
        public FK_ENTITY_TABLE_NAME FK_ENTITY_TABLE_NAME
        {
...
```

Therefore, when I use the  XmlSerializer / DataContractSerializer and on my  PARENT_ENTITY, it skips right over serializing my "FK_ENTITY_TABLE_NAME entity:

```
<PARENT_ENTITY>
(note: no FK_ENTITY_TABLE_NAME serialized here)
</PARENT_ENTITY>
```

Is there anything i can do to control the XmlIgnore attribute from being inserted in these generated files?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest first off to fix your naming convention. Other than that make sure that you expose a get method for your  DATA_ENTITY class so that it gets compiled into the generated code.

Also, why is your include for FK_ENTITY_TABLE_NAME but the entity class uses DATA_ENTITY? That seems strange to me. Is there any other relevant code you haven't included?

Comment: Naming is strictly to hide my implementation details, guess i should have used some Aventureworks samples :)  DATA_ENTITY was a typo.. i have fixed this.